# How to change the action of the first tabbaritem (when clicked)

Tags: iphone, click, action, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to show a tableviewcontroller as the first page, with the tabbarcontroller in it.
After it is shown I would like to change the action of the first item in the tabbarcontroller to show a menu.

I have created the menu, I only need to find a way to change the click event of the first item on the tabbarcontroller.

I've been searching for hours now, and help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Tommy

*edit: I found the solution, I will post it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a good way to handle this problem...

I used the UITabBarController delegate and implemented this:

```
 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
  if([viewController.title isEqualToString:@"YourTitleHere"])
  {
     // do your stuff here
  }else
  {
     return YES;
  }
}
```

this Worked great for me, very happy that I finally found a solution! Hope this helps others as well!

Answer (score 0):

Implement

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{ 
    if(tabBar.selectedItem.tag == 0)
    {
        RootViewController *objRootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objRootViewController animated:YES];
        [objRootViewController release];
    }
}`

Comment: I implemented the UITabBarDelegate and the UITabBarControllerDelegate
But I get the error that I can't change the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller. Any ideas?